# How to get logged in user details in oim request data validation?

Tags: validation, request, oim

I want to get the userlogin and city attribute details of the (requester) logged in user raising the request in OIM.

I want to process the validation according to certain attributes of requester city attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `oracle.iam.platform.context.ContextManager` class and call various methods available with it.

e.g. `ContextManager.getOrigUser();` should give you requester's login.